# How to hide white rectangle when hovering a button?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I want to make button hover effect in Qt Creator, Qt Quick 6.5.

The below code works, but then a white rectangle appears.

```
Button {
    anchors.left: inputFromUser.right; anchors.leftMargin: 5
    id: getUserValue
    height: 62
    width: 50

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea2
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onPressed: { bacgroundRectangle.color = 'red' }
        onReleased: { bacgroundRectangle.color = 'gray' }
    }
                        
    background: Rectangle {
        id: bacgroundRectangle
        border.width:5
        color: mouseArea2.containsMouse ? "blue" : "green"
        radius: width/4
    }
    
    onClicked: {
        if (inputFromUser.text !==""){
            chatModel.send(inputFromUser.text)
            chatModel.gpt(inputFromUser.text)
            bling.text = chatModel.cnt()
            inputFromUser.text = ""
        }
    }
}
```

Default:

[image: Default]

When hovering:

[image: When hovering]

I tried to create a button inside the rectangle and make the rectangle hover, and it works, but the button appeared as a smaller inner rectangle, maybe there is some method to make button transparent, but `color: "transparent"` doesn't work.

Comment: I actually doubt it's working like intended on all cases, since you are overwriting the binding on containsMouse from inside the onReleased and onPressed handlers. However, this does not explain the white when hovering, did you perhaps miss a warning log?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit odd to have MouseArea overlapping a Button. They both are competing for handling mouse events. As far as I can tell, all your requirements should be handled by the button itself, e.g.

```
        Button {
            id: btn
            Layout.preferredHeight: 62
            Layout.preferredWidth: 50
            hoverEnabled: true
            background: Rectangle {
                color: btn.pressed && "red"
                    || btn.hovered && "blue"
                    || "grey"
            }
        }
```